# Azure Functions how to return an HttpResponse or display a message before the script finishes

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I have a Python Azure Function that is one file and one `main` function:

```
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    [bunch of code]

    return func.HttpResponse("the file will be deleted in 10 minutes", status_code=200)
```

It creates a file inside Azure Blob storage for the user and deletes it in 10 minutes. I use `time.sleep(600)`  to do this. However, the message only arrives at the end of this timer, after the file has already been deleted.

**How can I make the HttpResponse show the message before the script ends, then wait 10 minutes before deleting the message?**

I've tried adding `func.HttpResponse('the file will be deleted in 10 minutes')` before the `time.sleep(600)` but it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a Function with http output binding like this you have to `return` the http response at the end for the response to work. So with a single Function, you cannot achieve this. Continue reading for the alternate solution.

This problem is typically an 'asynchronous' processing example where you want to respond immediately like "ok, I am going to do this" while it "queues further processing" to be continued in the backend. To achieve this in Azure Function you will need 2 functions as below:

1. Function 1 : [Http trigger, http output](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=python) and [Queue output binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-output?tabs=python) (for simplicity I will use storage queue).
2. Function 2 : [Queue trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-trigger?tabs=python) (will get triggered by the message queued by function 1).

### Function 1 (update according to your need):

JSON:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    },
    {
      "type": "queue",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "msg",
      "queueName": "outqueue",
      "connection": "AzureStorageQueuesConnectionString"
    }
  ]
}
```

Code:

```
import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest, msg: func.Out[str]) -> func.HttpResponse:
    [bunch of code]
    input_msg = "<create the message body required by function 2>"
    msg.set(input_msg)
    return func.HttpResponse("the file will be deleted in 10 minutes", status_code=201)
```

### Function 2 (update according to your need):

JSON:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "msg",
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "messages",
      "connection": "AzureStorageQueuesConnectionString"
    }
  ]
}
```

Code:

```
import json
import azure.functions as func

def main(msg: func.QueueMessage):  
     # below is just an example of parsing the message, in your case it might be taking the blob info required for deleting
     message = json.dumps({
        'id': msg.id,
        'body': msg.get_body().decode('utf-8'),
        'expiration_time': (msg.expiration_time.isoformat()
                            if msg.expiration_time else None),
        'insertion_time': (msg.insertion_time.isoformat()
                           if msg.insertion_time else None),
        'time_next_visible': (msg.time_next_visible.isoformat()
                              if msg.time_next_visible else None),
        'pop_receipt': msg.pop_receipt,
        'dequeue_count': msg.dequeue_count
    })

    [bunch of code]
```

**NOTE: You can also look at [Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=python) where you can handle complex workflow and would not need to manage the queueing yourself. But since your scenario in this case is quite simple, I did not cover it.**

Comment: Dang it, lightning fast. But at least we think alike.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the actual response isn't sent before the function itself returns something to the pipeline - the pipeline will then return the result to the caller.

And instead of doing this wonky 10-minute waiting *inside* a function app (which is something you really never should do), I'd create a queue message, set the initial invisibility to 10 minutes, add to e.g. `delete-file-queue`. Have a `QueueTrigger` somewhere, listening to `delete-file-queue`, and do the deletion of the file.

So instead, do something like this (I'm not super familiar with Functions in python, so treat this as pseudo code):

```py
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    # handle whatever you have to, but do NOT include time.sleep
    queue_client.send_message("path/to/blob", visibility_timeout=600)
    # the message will end up in the back of the queue, and 
    # it'll stay invisible for 600 seconds
    # this is something we don't have to wait for, and thus, the following
    # will return immediately
    return func.HttpResponse("file will be deleted in 10 minutes")
```

Your QueueTrigger would then be something like this:

```py
def main(filename: func.QueueMessage, inputblob: func.InputStream) -> None:
    # check if inputblob is none, if not, delete it
```

In your `functions.json`, you should include bindings for the `filename` and `inputblob`:

```json
{
  "name": "filename",
  "type": "queueTrigger",
  "direction": "in",
  "queueName": "delete-file-queue",
  "connection": "MyStorageConnectionString"
},
{
  "name": "inputblob",
  "type": "blob",
  "path": "{queueTrigger}",
  "connection": "MyStorageConnectionString",
  "direction": "in"
}
```

[Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-python-how-to-use-queue-storage?tabs=python) to initializing a `queue_client`.
And more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-trigger?tabs=python#example).